# Python - % Symbol and Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I'm creating a Python script for my Raspberry Pi Radio. The Pi used mpd/mpc to play music, and I can type in the following command in Terminal to see information about the currently playing station:

```
mpc current -f "[%position%]"
```

This will show me:

```
11
```

As the 11th radio station is playing.

My problem is, when I put this in Python to extract this number to use as part of my code, it gives me this: **(I get a ^ under the first % symbol)**

```
f=os.open("mpc current -f "[%position%]"")                      
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This seems odd as I have already used similar commands in a Python script which have worked, however they have not had the % symbol in them. Such as:

```
  f=os.popen("mpc current")
```

I am still learning Python so would appreciate it if someone could correct me here, as the command seems legit to me, especially with the "" either side. I even tried using ' instead of ", but if I do, the command doesn't work.

Comment: Hint:  Look at the syntax highlighting in the question

Comment: Even without this problem, this can't possibly be right. `os.open` opens a file, it doesn't run a program. So, unless you happen to have a file named `mpc current -f "[%position%]"`, with the spaces and quotes and so on as part of the filename, this will just give you an `OSError` for `ENOENT`. (Actually, I believe you'll get a `TypeError` for not passing a `mode` before you even get that far.)

Comment: And consider using `subprocess` instead.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comments. This is part of the mpc program that runs the mpd (music player daemon). Here is a link to the commands (http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpc). Someone actually put the answer up then deleted it, all I have to do is change the outer "" to '' and it works!

Comment: @user2723392: How does that answer the comments? You can't `os.open` a command. (You can `os.popen` a command, but only if you want to use a function has been deprecated for years and is officially obsolete on 2.6+ and removed from 3.0+.) The code you've given us will _not_ work just by changing the quotes to single quotes. Maybe your real code will, but we can't see your real code, only what you've posted here.

Comment: Sorry, I do use os.popen at the moment, I think I took out the 'p' while trying to fix it myself. I didn't know it was depreciated - I just took it from a guide I found, that's kind of how i'm learning, one RPi project at a time. I'm very new to Python, and programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python sees

```
"string"[%
```

ans because `%` is not a valid array subscript, it points out the syntax error.

```
os.open('string"[%]"')
```

is valid syntax, but "doesn't work" for unrelated reasons. Namely, the argument to `os.open` should be a valid file name. To run an external command, you want to use [`subprocess`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you - this fixed it. I know (from other comments) that my method is depreciated and probably not the 'right' way of doing things, but I'm learning from tutorials and how-to guides, so I'm just copying and learning bits every time. I guess my full code (internet radio) would explain, but too late for that I guess.